# Why is GHC distributed with gcc and g++?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi

On Windows, GHC is distributed with gcc and g++, e.g. under `ghc-7.6.3\mingw\bin`.  From the [download page](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3), it is also noted under the windows binary download that the build for Windows "also includes support for compiling C++ files."

I could imagine that distributing these compilers is just for convenience, since Windows doesn't come with any.  I could also imagine it is *necessary* for using the FFI, but I'm not 100% sure.  For instance, although GHC will compile .c and .cpp files using it's own gcc/g++ compilers, GHC also [provides options](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.3/html/users_guide/options-phases.html#replacing-phases) to choose whichever compiler and linker you want.  And indeed, you can specify your own gcc/g++ and it seems to work.  You can even cut GHC out of the loop a little further by compiling the .c/.cpp files in advance, and only invoking GHC to compile the Haskell code and link it all using `-pgml` (although the overall effect is the same as using `-pgmc` and `-pgml`).

Now that *seems* to work, but does it rely on pure luck that you specify `-pgml` and `-pgmc` to be a version of gcc that is compatible with what GHC has in mind?  In other words, when I use the FFI, am I really only supposed to compile and link everything with GHC invocations?

Comment: Using GHC for everything is generally the easiest way. And (I may be mistaken) if I recall correctly, things don't work too well if you try to use MSVC (and I have the vague memory that Cygwin has problems too).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

GHC is generally compatible with many/several versions of GCC (the incompatibilities appear when using the evil mangler).

If you try using other C compilers, you'll have a few low level issues to contend with (flags, asm formats).

Note that more recent GHCs deprecate the C backend in favor of the LLVM backend, making this somewhat moot for day-to-day Haskell development.

Comment: So if I've wrapped my head around this, the 'C backend' and the 'LLVM backend' (and the 'native code generator') all refer to a stage shortly before generating the object file for each Haskell module.  The evil mangler is part of the C backend only.  Excluding then the C backend, one can expect compatibility of GHC's object files (from .hs files) with GCC's object files (generated from .c/.cpp files) --- for some unspecified range of nearby GCC versions.  But for any backend (including LLVM?) you have those low level issues if you use a non-GCC compiler.